# Django model allow multiple

Tags: python, django

So I want to create a model, let's say "Cars"
I want to implement the field detail_name and detail_desc

```py
detail_name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
detail_desc= models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

But I want an admin to be able to add another detail_name and detail_desc if they wish to.

How can I implement that?

Comment: You mean that a Car can have many detail_name - detail_desc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) for this purpose.

Then your code will be similar to this:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    # some code here


class DetailInfo(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='details')
    detail_name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    detail_desc= models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then you can see all details by:

```py
car = Car.objects.first()  # just example, load first instance of Car
detail_infos = car.details.all()  # now detail_infos include queryset of all DetailInfo instances, that connected to Car
```

In [django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) you can add `details` as inlines (see [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline) for example).

## Example

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Car, DetailInfo

class DetailInfoInline(admin.TabularInline):  # you can use admin.TabularInline or admin.StackedInline here
    model = DetailInfo

@admin.register(Car)  # shortcut for admin.site.register()
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DetailInfoInline]
```

Comment: Hi, so I did what you suggested BUT had to change ``Car`` in ``car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='details')`` to ContentType. But now I cannot retrieve these details with ``detail_infos = car.details.all()`` Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Keyinator why you changed ```Car``` to ```ContentType```? Because ```ContentType``` is used in example link?

Comment: If I don't do it I get the following error ``ERRORS:
showcase.DetailInfo.content_object: (contenttypes.E004) 'DetailInfo.content_type' is not a ForeignKey to 'contenttypes.ContentType'.
        HINT: GenericForeignKeys must use a ForeignKey to 'contenttypes.ContentType' as the 'content_type' field.``

Comment: @Keyinator maybe you need to clear your database and migrations to fix this errors (if you already migrated this things).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200786/discussion-between-yevhenii-m-and-keyinator).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @Yevhenii M. for his help. Without him I wouldn't have gotten this working.
Following the code for my updated TabularInline

admin.py

```py
class DetailInfoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DetailInfo

class ShowCaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        DetailInfoInline,
    ]
```

models.py

```py
class DetailInfo(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    showcase = models.ForeignKey(ShowCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='details')
```